# Como impedir que um componente react seja renderizado mais de uma vez ao usar state

Tags: javascript, react

Estou aprendendo react e desenvolvendo uma tela onde ao abrir ele vai exibir uma lista de itens obtidos de uma API.
Nessa tela também tera um botão para atualizar a lista.

O código até agora é

```
//Componente
export default props =>{
    const [list, setList] = useState([])
    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
    
    //função que baixa a lista da api
    const fetchRequest = useCallback(() => { 
        fetch('url da api')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setList(data));
    }, [list]);
    
    //Aqui estou tentando impedir que a lista seja carregada mais de uma vez
    if (!loaded){
        fetchRequest()
        setLoaded(true)
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <button onClick={fetchRequest}>Atualizar</button>
            {list.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.canal}</div> )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Observe que a função fetchRequest() é chamada logo que o componente é renderizado e tambem quando clica no botão atualizar, eu inclui essa verificação if (!loaded)... com a intensão de impedir que o componente seja renderizado mais de uma vez sem necessidade.
Acontece que ainda assim ele renderiza 2 vezes e consequentemente carrega os dados da API 2 vezes.

Existe alguma forma de impedir que isso aconteça nesse caso?

Comment: Antes de responder a pergunta, queria chamar a atenção para o fato de que você colocou uma dependência desnecessária no `useCallback`. A variável `list` não está sendo usada na função, então você não precisa recriar essa função toda vez que `list` muda de valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira mais comum de buscar dados em uma API com React é usando o hook [`useEffect`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Esse hook recebe uma função e um array de dependências.

A função passada como primeiro argumento é executada na primeira renderização do componente e sempre que alguma das dependências muda de valor. Ou seja, quando você não passa nenhuma dependência, [nenhuma dependência muda de valor](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/022/138/highresrollsafe.jpg), então a função do `useEffect` só é executada uma vez.

Dito isso, o seu código final ficaria assim

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    
    //função que baixa a lista da api
    const fetchRequest = useCallback(() => { 
        fetch('url da api')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setList(data));
    }, []);
    
    useEffect(fetchRequest, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <button onClick={fetchRequest}>Atualizar</button>
            {list.map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item.canal}</div> )}
        </div>
    )
}
```